# How to access passed data inside a redirect route from Blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a method that redirect to a route like this with a data passed inside it:

```
return redirect('vendors')->with('vendor',$allvendors);
```

and I want to access the data that I passed from a blade template that the redirect is pointing to, so I did something like this:

```
@foreach($vendor as $vendors)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Undefined variable: vendor (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/easyhire-web/resources/views/vendor/vendors.blade.php)
```

I rely don't know what i am doing wrong, but when I return a view with that same data, it will work but if I change it to redirect, it will give error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[When redirecting, Laravel saves data to the session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data), so use the `session()` global helper to get saved data from the session:

```
@foreach (session('vendor') as $vendor)
```

Comment: I have a little issue using this method, if i refresh the page where the session is loaded it will tell me Invalid argument supplied for foreach() but it will load for the first time, so i think it's not saving. what can i do to this? i need to be saved.

Comment: That's how session works. You can reflash the data if you want, but a better way will be getting the data from DB in the method that renders the view (after redirecting).